# How do I define the Route for a .Net Core 3.1 webapi service call which takes an array of strings as a parameter?

Tags: c#, .net-core, routes, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm create a .NetCore 3.1 Web API Service.

I am having difficulties figuring out the correct routing definition for the service call.

**Consider the following definition:**

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("{paramA}/{paramB}")]
public void Sample(string paramA, string[] paramB)
{
}
```

What is the correct way to define my routing parameters when passing either
an array of strings? Should I be using List instead?

Comment: I'd pass `paramB` in querystring - `?paramB=1&paramB=2` etc

Comment: Any reason you want the variables in the route? You can put paramB in the body and .net will figure it out. This could also prevent exceeding the max url length depending on your use case.

Comment: @knowonecanknow - I don't quite follow you. Can you elobarate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you could pass the array list by query string:

```
[HttpPut]   
[Route("{paramA}")]
public void Sample([FromRoute]string paramA, [FromQuery]string[] paramB)
{
}
```

Send Request like:`https://localhost:5001/xxxxxx/aaa?paramB=ss&paramB=sd`.

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to pass the Arraay strings on the body of the request in a HttpPost, this is the part of the request where you don't have character limitations, when in the url of the query you will have something like 300 character limits.

For example:

```
HttpPost]
[Route("MyArrayStrings")]
public async string MyArrayStrings([FromBody] string content)
{
    return content;
}
```

And then, you can use Newtonsoft for serialize the data when sending the request, and for Deserialize when received.

Comment: `when in the url of the query you will have something like 300 character limits.` 2000+ generally (and that is assuming IE11 is supported).